# How to create a HashMap that receives different types?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I need to send String and Integer values ​​to the application, but if I keep it that way, it says that HashMap expects both the key and value as str

```
let mut json_data = HashMap::new();
json_data.insert("jql","project=ABC");
json_data.insert("startAt",0);
json_data.insert("maxResults",1);
```

How can I maintain this dynamically? Passing Strings and Integers whenever I want?

Comment: [`enum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.enum.html)

Comment: In this case, since you're ultimately trying to represent JSON, your JSON library of choice should have a `Value` enum available to represent any JSON value

Comment: How would that look?

Comment: For example like [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/enum.Value.html)